# getting error for client = boto3.client('organizations')

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-organizations

getting error for:

```
client = boto3.client('organizations')
```

> botocore.exceptions.UnknownServiceError: Unknown service:
>   'organizations'

Comment: Are you running the python script while using credentials for your consolidated billing account? If your credentials are for one of the organization's accounts (not the root account), the service wouldn't be available

Comment: What version of boto3 are you using?  The error suggests that boto3 just doesn't know about the ``organizations`` service.

Comment: Thanks, upgrading botocore fixed this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just run, pip install botocore --upgrade